# How do I properly post a decimal value in a Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a POCO model as follows:

```
public class Tool
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int QtyOnHand { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.####}")]
    public decimal SizeUS { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int OriginalID { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool Selectable { get; set; }

}
```

In my Razor View I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SizeUS)                    
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeUS)
```

The problem that I have is the SizeUS value gets rounded to the 1/100th when posted to the controller.  I want to be able to post a value of up to 1/1000th or maybe 1/10000th.  How would I do so ?

Comment: What happens if you remove your `DisplayFormat` attribute? If that fixes the issue you could always use an HTML helper to format the decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how the `decimal` editor is defined for currency reasons:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
    private object FormattedValue {
        get {
            if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model) {
                return String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                     "{0:0.00}",
                                     ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
            }
            return ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

> This template displays decimal values with 2 digits of precision by default, since most users will use decimal values to represent currency. Note that it only does this if you haven’t applied a format string (which is the purpose of the check in the if statement).
>       <%= Html.Encode(FormattedValue) %>

ref: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

You can either use `double` instead, create your own editor template, or simply write out a HTML `input` control.